# Why am I getting this error when I am trying to run my Discord bot

Tags: python, discord, replit

Why am I getting this error when I am trying to run my Discord bot

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bw4OU.png ....

Comment: Please do not provide program output or error messages as image files.  Copy the text of the output or error message and paste it directly into your question.  It is usually most appropriate to format such text as code or as a block of quoted text (use the appropriate toolbar button in the question editor).

Answer (score 0):

The very first character of your code is a space character.  That shouldn't be there.  Instead of this:

```
 import discord
from discord.ext import commands
```

your code should be this:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
```

Answer (score 0):

As @CryptoFool said, it is indentation issue. You can also install some helper add-on/plugins to your IDE to help you with that.

For example consider below IDE:Plugin

[Intellij:Indent Rainbow](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/13308-indent-rainbow)

[Visual Studio:Indent Rainbow](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=oderwat.indent-rainbow)

Comment: how to add a plugin? I am new to python

Comment: I tried doing what @CryptoFool said, but it's showing File "main.py", line 19, in <module>

Comment: I didn't add anything in line 19

Comment: I only used 8 lines

Comment: Now it's spamming Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 19, in <module>